# SQL select rows from two different tables with different column names

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I want to select rows from two different tables(TABLE_A and TABLE_B). I'm using oracle db and hibernate. Here are my tables:

Here is `TABLE_A`

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID | AMOUNT | BALANCE |  STATUS   |     CREATE_DATE     |      END_DATE       |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      5 |       5 | FINISHED  | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 |
|  2 |     12 |      17 | TIMED_OUT | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 |
|  3 |     21 |      38 | COMMITED  | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is `TABLE_B`

```
+----+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+
| ID | PAYMENT_AMOUNT | TOTAL_BALANCE | PAYMENT_STATUS |  REQUEST_TIMESTAMP  |
+----+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |              3 |            23 | FAILED         | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 |
|  2 |             12 |            11 | FULFILLED      | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 |
|  3 |              2 |             9 | TIMED_OUT      | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 |
+----+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

What I want to do is that I need to get a result like the following with a single query:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| AMOUNT | BALANCE |  STATUS   |        DATE         |      END_DATE       |
+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      5 |       5 | FINISHED  | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 |
|     12 |      17 | TIMED_OUT | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 |
|     21 |      38 | COMMITED  | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 |
|      3 |      23 | FAILED    | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 | null                |
|     12 |      11 | FULFILLED | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 | null                |
|      2 |       9 | TIMED_OUT | 2014-02-27 15:10:20 | null                |
+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The results are `ordered by DATE`. Column descriptions are the following:

```
AMOUNT = TABLE_A.AMOUNT or TABLE_B.PAYMENT_AMOUNT
BALANCE = TABLE_A.BALANCe or TABLE_B.TOTAL_BALANCE
STATUS = TABLE_A.STATUS or TABLE_B.PAYMENT_STATUS
DATE = TABLE_A.CREATE_DATE or TABLE_B.REQUEST_TIMESTAMP
END_DATE = TABLE_A.END_DATE or null
```

Is there any way to get those kind of results in oracle db and any way to bind those results to a hibernate object in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
select * from (
select id as amount, ... from t1
union all 
select id as amount, ... from t2
) t order by date
```